# Hola! Deseo imprimir solamente una columna de un archivo csv en python. Pero me sale error

Tags: python-3.x

El archivo csv es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy realizando:

```js
import csv
with open('tabla_datos.csv') as datos:
    dreader = csv.DictReader(datos)
    for row in dreader:
        print(row["Nombre"])
```

Donde me aparece error es en "print(row["Nombre"])" y lo que deseo hacer es darle print a la que dice nombre.

Answer (score 0):

Con los datos que aportas, si debería funcionarte, siempre que el fichero este accesible.

Igualmente si te da error, es que hay algo que depurar.

1. Obtén el tipo de `excepción` que se crea. Busca o añadala a la pregunta.
2. Prueba con `print(row)`en lugar de `print(row["Nombre"])` y veras si hay algún problema con los `field_names`. En caso que igualmente de error, tienes un problema con la lectura del fichero. O si no imprime nada, puede ser que el fichero esté vacío...
3. No lo pruebes con `code snippets` / consolas de python online, ya que no tendran el fichero accesible.

[csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)